# how to remove the close button in dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to hide the close button in the title bar of the dialog box. I want the user strictly complete the steps in dialog, so restrict the ways of hiding the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

---

You can hide close button on dialog's open event.

Ref : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open

This event is triggered when dialog is opened.
Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the open event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Bind to the open event by type: dialogopen.

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, use CSS...

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
display:none;
}
```